# How to read a property from a Blazor RenderComponentAsync within Parent MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 MVC Razor View `Index.cshtml` containing the code `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<DropDownSystemList>(RenderMode.Server, new { IndexViewModel = Model }))` to which I have a corresponding razor file, but how do I access the `ReasonClass` property from `DropDownSystemList` in the parent Razor View `Index.cshtml`?

For example, if I select from the generated DropDownSystemList, the onchange event will trigger the Show method of DropDownSystemList Blazor Component and in turn set the property ReasonClass. I would like to use that ReasonClass in the parent View, for example something similar to the following:

```
<div class="row mb-3 @ReasonClass" id="Reason">
   
</div>
```

Please note that @ReasonClass does not work, it is for reference only.

**DropDownSystemList.razor**

```
@using Application.ViewModels

<select class="col-sm-3 form-select" @onchange="Show" required="required">

    @if (IndexViewModel?.SystemList != null)
    {
        foreach (var selectListItemDto in IndexViewModel.SystemList)
        {
            <option value="@selectListItemDto.Value">@selectListItemDto.Text</option>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }

</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IndexViewModel? IndexViewModel { get; set; }
    
    public string? ReasonClass { get; set; } = "d-none";

    public void Show(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {
        ReasonClass = changeEventArgs.Value?.ToString() == "SYS1" ? "" : "d-none";
    }
}
```

I could be going down the rabbit hole with this one, but trying a slightly different approach to utilise the existing js file to target the DOM object, however getting an error `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'checkSystem' ('checkSystem' was undefined)` with the following code:

```
@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? JsObjectReference { get; set; }

    //private string? SelectedSystemId { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IndexViewModel? IndexViewModel { get; set; }

    public bool? Reason { get; set; }

    public async Task Show(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {
        //SelectedSystemId = changeEventArgs.Value?.ToString();

        Reason = changeEventArgs.Value?.ToString() == "SYS1";

        await JsObjectReference!.InvokeVoidAsync("checkSystem", Reason);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            JsObjectReference = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/homeIndex.js");
        }
    }
}
```

**homeIndex.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    function checkSystem(value) {
        if (value) {
            showDiv("#Reason");
        } else {
            hideDiv("#Reason");
        }
    }

    function showDiv(div) {
        if (window.$(div).hasClass("d-none")) {
            window.$(div).removeClass("d-none");
        }
    }

    function hideDiv(div) {
        if (!window.$(div).hasClass("d-none")) {
            window.$(div).addClass("d-none");
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure why I am getting the invoke error, the callback(state) is processed correctly via the the import, so seems like the file is imported. I've tested that by modifying the location and when set wrong I would get an error at the import process, so a little confused as to why the invoke error.

Comment: Maybe you could try use dependency injection instance in both blazor and mvc.